# How to rebuild same keystore and certificate with apktool

Tags: android, android-keystore, apktool

I only want modified apk but **keep keystore and certificate unchange**. How to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you changed the package name then you will need a new keystore and certificate otherwise you can use the saved keystore example: while updating apps.Please read through the link below.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html#publishing-build

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your apk to play store than Before you upload you must **consider these things**,

> - The .apk must be signed with the same private key.
> - Package name and signing certificate must match those of the existing    version.
> - Must incremented android:versionCode and android:versionName in    manifest file.

NOW,

> - Go to the play store(SignIn),
> - Create new app, put name, decription etc and upload that file.
> - Make changes/improvements/bug fixed to your app, export it with the    SAME signed key, it generates another file.
> - Go to the play store, enter the existing app, upload the new file,    mark it as active.

Visit [Market Upgrade](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#marketupgrade).